# Customize Email Alerts with Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

With a self-managed deployment of TFS it is possible to customize the format for TFS email alerts, by editing transform files such as 'WorkItemChangedEvent.xsl'.

Is there a way of acheiving the same with Visual Studio Online?

Comment: Hi @holf Any luck with this? looking to do the same thing and no luck so far.

Comment: @Aram Not yet! :-(

Answer (score -1):

No, its possible to customize email alerts format with Visual Studio Online.